# Set line widths according to column for seaborn FacetGrid with lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like to pick out a certain line in each lineplot in a FacetGrid, to highlight the "default" setting compared to the other options.

I've tried to make a minimal example based on [this random walk example in the seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_facets.html)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rs = np.random.RandomState(2020)
pos = rs.randint(-1, 2, (20, 5)).cumsum(axis=1)
pos -= pos[:, 0, np.newaxis]
step = np.tile(range(5), 20)
walk = np.repeat(range(20), 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[pos.flat, step, walk],
                  columns=["position", "step", "walk"])
df["family"] = df["walk"] % 5
df["top"] = df.groupby("walk")["position"].transform("max")
df["importance"] = df["top"]+1
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="family", col_wrap=3,  hue="walk")
grid.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "step", "position", marker="o")
grid.add_legend()
```

This gives me faceted line plots with all lines the same width (of course):

[image: first attempt]

I have created an extra column called `importance`; I would like the line width to be set according to this column.  I can see that with a simple `seaborn.lineplot` you can "Assign the `size` semantic to map the width of the lines with a numeric variable".  I have tried to use `size=` in the FacetGrid() call and in the `map_dataframe()` call, but it's not working.

For example, if I use this instead:

```py
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="family", col_wrap=3,  hue="walk")
grid.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "step", "position",
                   size="importance", marker="o")
grid.add_legend()
```

I see no difference in line thickness, but now the legend is messed up too:

[image: second attempt]

Comment: `grid.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "step", "position", size='importance', marker="o") `What if you set the importance to the size of the line plot? In my environment, the graph is drawn with different line widths. The difference in line widths is subtle.

Comment: I have tried that, but see no discernable difference in line width (it should be significant, ranging between 1 and 4); but I do get the legend messed up instead.  I'll work it into the question to show the result.

Comment: `grid.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "step", "position", size='importance', marker="o", legend=False) ` Can you try this

Comment: @r-beginners Unfortunately, still the same result - all lines same width, but now no legend: https://pasteboard.co/JyD6FCc.png

Comment: [https://pasteboard.co/JyDbKEJ.png](https://pasteboard.co/JyDbKEJ.png)I uploaded the image using the service you provided. It looks very useful.

Comment: @r-beginners thanks, but I still don't see any different thickness in lines - the "importance" column should make the lines with the higher maximums thicker.  I don't see that in your upload - am I missing something?

Comment: The image I posted is provided for the legend only. Did the legend turn out as intended?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224024/discussion-between-mr-felix-u-and-r-beginners).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm too busy right now to respond to the chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `importance` is the same in a given `hue` level, and that `sizes` seem to be normalized at the levels of `hue`, so they end up being all the same. You can, however, pass a mapping dictionary to `sizes=` to match a given `size` to a particular `linewidth`

```py
sizes = {a:a for a in df['importance'].unique()}
```

> ```
> {1: 1, 4: 4, 2: 2, 3: 3}
> ```

```py
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="family", col_wrap=3,  hue="walk", height=2)
grid.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, "step", "position",
                   size="importance", marker="o", sizes=sizes)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!  That's great, thank you.  For some reason, the legend now messes up, with some entries just showing black and without marker - not really a problem as I'm not actually using the marker='o' setting in my real graph.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, and I couldn't figure why the legend comes out that way